# Curious about some (basic?) linear algebra notation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trigonometry, notation

I was reading an old linear algebra textbook today, and I was actually having some trouble understanding the notation given in a problem. Here is what it said (or something similar):
Consider the $n \times n$-matrix $Q$ given by $Q=(Q_{i,j})_{i,j=1,\ldots,n}$ with $Q_{i,j}=\sin (j/(\cos i + \sin j))$

If $n$ were $4$ or $5$ let's say, what would this matrix look like? The notation first given for $Q$ is throwing me off.

Comment: It is giving a formula for the $i,j$th entry of $Q$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first part $Q = (Q_{ij})$ is saying that the entry in the $i$th row and $j$th column of $Q$ is the number $Q_{i,j}$. And $i,j = 1, \ldots,n$ is saying that both $i$ and $j$ each range from 1 to $n$ so your matrix $Q$ is $n \times n$. The formula for that entry $Q_{i,j}$ is given by the second equation you cited. Not sure how to further explain that part...

Comment: Awesome-ly fast response! I didnt know that the second part was just giving the range (dont see the point of that) but now it makes sense! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$Q_{1,2}=\sin(2/(\cos 1+\sin 2)$. Does that help?

Comment: Wait, so what does "i,j=1,...,n" mean?
Which is the second part of the subscript on the first notation given for Q

Comment: It means $i=1,\ldots,n$ and $j=1,\ldots, n$.  In other words $i$ and $j$ both range through all integers between $1$ and $n$.

Comment: That makes sense now, thanks Tim!

Comment: You're welcome. :)